# Как написать явную специализацию для шаблона с параметрами по умолчанию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, дружественная-функция

```
template<typename Type, size_t size = 10>
class Array
{
    Type* p;
public:
    Array();
    ~Array() {};

    template<typename T, size_t sz>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<T, size>&);
};

template<typename Type, size_t size>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<Type, size>& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        os << a.p[i] << std::endl;

    return os;
}
```

не могу понять как сделать явную специализацию для шаблона с параметром по умолчанию.

Если пишу

```
template<>
```

то неизвестен размер массива

Если так:

```
template<size_t size> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<double, size>& a)
```

то

> Ошибка    C2248   Array::p: невозможно обратиться к private член,
>   объявленному в классе "Array"

Comment: а что вы выводить собираетесь, когда у вас  Type* p  ни на что не указывет,? Даже конструктор не инициализирует его ничем,  и не определены  конструктор копирования,  оператор присваивания,  а деструктор ничего не делает, что приведет к печальным последствиям, если даже  указатель  будете инициализировать

Comment: я просто не стал сюда вставлять все определения, . Для примера взял фунцию operator<<. Сначала у меня было поле класса, которое хранило размер, и был один параметр шаблона, там я разобрался со специализацией.

Comment: вы обьвляете оператор как друг класса, потом пытаетесь определять еще и другой такой же оператор, который не является ни другом, ни членом класса, и естественно для него закрытые данные недоступны

Comment: Какой именно шаблон из этих двух не получается специализировать и для каких параметров? В заголовке речь вроде идет о шаблоне с параметром по-умолчанию, т.е. о шаблоне класса, а в тексте вопроса почему-то начинает писаться шаблон оператора.

Comment: надо специализировать friend функцию operator<< для типа double например. Получается можно же в шаблоном классе отдельные методы специализировать, а не весь класс.

Comment: Ну во-первых `operator<<` это просто отдельная шаблонная функция, а не метод класса. Во-вторых, такое ощущение что вы хотите специализировать только `Type`, а `size` оставить как параметр шаблона, так?

Comment: Да так, size должен сохранить значение, или наверное можно добавить поле в класс и инициализировать его параметром из шаблона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Специализация только по `Type` с сохранением `size` в качестве параметра шаблона называется *частичная специализация*. Частичная специализация для шаблонов функций не разрешается. Однако с новыми средствами можно достаточно легко обойти это ограничение:

```
template<typename Type, size_t size>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<Type, size>& a)
{
    if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<Type, double>)
    {  // вариант для double
       for(size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
       {
           os << std::setprecision(9) << a.p[i] << std::endl;
       }
    }
    else
    {  // обычный вариант
       for(size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
       {
           os << a.p[i] << std::endl;
       }
    }
    return os;
}
```

В более старых версия стандарта такого же эффекта можно было бы добиться вынеся реализацию метода в специальный шаблонный класс и написав частичную специализацию для этого класса:

```
template<typename T, size_t size> class
PrintImpl final
{
    public: static void
    Invoke(std::ostream& os, T const * const p)
    { 
        for(size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
        {
           os << p[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

template<size_t size> class
PrintImpl<double, size> final
{
    public: static void
    Invoke(std::ostream& os, T const * const p)
    { 
        for(size_t i{}; i < size; ++i)
        {
           os << std::setprecision(9) << p[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

template<typename Type, size_t size>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array<Type, size>& a)
{
     PrintImpl<Type, size>::Invoke(os, a.p);
     return os;
}
```